# EF 4 Code First: Define Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have following entities:

```
public class Product { 
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    //other properties
}

public Coupon {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CouponCode> CouponCodes { get; set; }
}
```

I am configuring `DbModelBuilder` as follows:

```
var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
builder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

builder.Entity<Coupon>().HasKey(a => a.Id);
//other properties
builder.Entity<Coupon>().HasMany(x => x.CouponCodes);
builder.Entity<Coupon>().HasMany(x => x.Products);
```

This scheme is creating `Coupon_Id` in **Products** table. Actually I want to register all the product codes for which the given `Coupun` is valid. The way EF is interpreting it is obviously wrong as there an be multiple coupons valid for one **Product** entity.

Kindly help me find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupon { get; set; } will define the navigational property from product to coupon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have many-to-many relation you must instruct EF to create it.

```
builder.Entity<Coupon>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithMany();
```